# Given an array of integers, find the length of the largest subarray such that atleast 1 number (from the first k numbers) is not present in it

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary

Problem: We're given an array of integers with integers ranging from 1 to k. It is not necessary that all the k integers are present. 
Eg. k = 3 and Array = [1,2,1,1,2] 
Find the length of the largest subarray such that atleast one integer from 1 to k is absent.
Example: For k = 3 and array = [1,2,1,1,2], Answer = 5 
For k = 2 and array = [1,2,1,1,2], Answer = 2.
My code:

```
def ans(A, n, k): #A is the array and n is the length
    d = {}
    if k > n:
        return n
    for i in range(n):
        if A[i] in d:
            d[A[i]].append(i)
        else:
            d[A[i]] = [i]
    max_diff = 0
    if len(d) != k:
        return n
    for j in d:
        r = len(d[j])
        if r == 1:
            diff = max(n-d[j][-1]-1, d[j][0])
        else:
            diff = max(d[j][0], r - d[j][-1]-1)
            for i in range(r-1):
                diff = max(diff, d[j][i+1] - d[j][i]-1)
        max_diff = max(max_diff, diff)
    return max_diff
```

However, the code gives <del>runtime error and</del>  wrong answers for some hidden test cases. What is the possible error? And the possible test cases which are giving wrong answers?

Explanation for diff : Basically for each number in the array, it is finding the stretchs i.e. the interval lengths in which that partcular element is not present. For the second example, d becomes {1:[0,2,3], 2:[1,4]}. In case of two, there exists a subarray without two on index 0 i.e. length =1 so, diff would be 1. Then there is no two in the subarray from index 2 to 3 (inclusive). Thus, diff = 2.

EDIT: Taking in consideration the comments, I've made a few changes in the code and it no longer gives a runtime error but I still have Wrong Answer on some hidden test cases.
Problem link in case you want to try: https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA02/problems/NOTALLFL

Comment: you can't subtract an array from an integer, why pass `n` into the function. Trying to decipher your method you are using the wrong method, explain what you want to do with this `diff`

Comment: I really dont get your example. I really would like to help, but it is not clear for me.

Comment: When you attempted to debug using print statements did you find parts of the code that were doing what you expected? Which parts of the code were misbehaving?

Comment: @superbrain I just made a change, there are still some failing cases.

Comment: @wwii I actually did but it is working correct for the test cases I'm putting in so, I'm unable to notice any unusual behaviour.

Comment: @rioV8, basically for each number in the array, it is finding the stretchs i.e. the interval lengths in which that partcular element is not present. For the second example, d becomes {1:[0,2,3], 2:[1,4]}. In case of two, there exists a subarray without two on index 0 i.e. length =1 so, diff would be 1. Then there is no two in the subarray from index 2 to 3 (inclusive). Thus, diff = 2.

Comment: @MisterNox Please check if this is helpful, the same concept: https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA02/problems/NOTALLFL

Comment: @rioV8 yeah I changed it now. It's still giving WA on some cases

Comment: Is this problem online somewhere, so that we could try out our solution attempts there?

Comment: @superbrain https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA02/problems/NOTALLFL

Comment: Did you figure this out? Do you want to know what is wrong with yours or do you want an alternative method?

Comment: for the case that gets wrong use a debugger and try to find the cause

Comment: my prev comment was wrong. How to find the test case that gives the wrong answer? I have submitted my solution but it gives a Wrong Answer in the K=2 cases (Sub Task 1)

Comment: @wwii, I figured the problem and added my answer as well.

Comment: @rioV8, the test cases are hidden. You have to try putting in multiple cases yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code gives a wrong answer for the input:

```
k = 2
array = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

The change should be in the 18th line
i.e. instead of

```
 diff = max(d[j][0], r - d[j][-1]-1)
```

It should be

```
 diff = max(d[j][0], n - d[j][-1]-1)
```

It's a tiny mistake but caused failure for a lot of test cases.

Comment: @wwii this is what I was looking for as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @rioV8 the problem is that the question won't make sense then cause the code would work

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below:

target = @, all other numbers = -.

```
A = { - - - @ - @ @ - - - - - - @ - @ - - - - - - - - - - - }
```

If we want to find the subarray that does not contain @, we can treat the entire array as being enclosed by @, such that:

```
A` = { @ - - - @ - @ @ - - - - - - @ - @ - - - - - - - - - - - @ }
```

Then, it's just a matter of - tracking the last encountered position of @, and the largest difference between 2 consecutive occurrences of @.  @ could be any number between 1..k, so it could be tracked by an array of size "k".

C++ code would be something like (please test for off-by-1 error as I expect it to be there:

```
int subarr(int* A, size_t n, int k)
{
   if (n < k)
   {
      return n;
   }

   size_t max = 0;
   std::vector<size_t> lastPos(k);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < lastPos.size(); i++)
   {
      lastPos[i] = -1;
   }

   // Find the longest subArray when excluding a single digit of the digits present.
   for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
     if ((i - lastPos[A[i]]) > max)
     {
        max = i - lastPos[A[i]];
     }
     lastPos[A[i]] = i;
   }

   // Check for last
   for (size_t i = 0; i < lastPos.size(); i++)
   {
     if ((i - lastPos[A[i]]) == -1)
     {
        return n;
     }
   }

   return max - 1;
}
```

Comment: The answer for an array [1, 2, 5, 7, 9 ] and k = 9 would be 5 because, if we consider the whole array, i.e. length = 5, there is still 3 or 4 or 6 or 8 which aren't present in the array.

Comment: You're considering that k should be absent. The question is: any one number from the set of integers from 1 to k should be absent.

Comment: OK I adjusted the answer to your question clarification - any one number not k specifically.

Comment: I used a similar approach. Though, I used a hash map instead of a list which would greatly help in making it efficient.

Comment: Hashmap will be more expensive than using the vector/dynarray, since hashmap needs to allocate node objects, check for collision etc.

Comment: you use `std::vector` but why not for the function argument `A`, you forget to check for the closing sentinel

Comment: The size of A is determined by the caller.  Could replace A and n with vector.  Corrected checking the closing sentinel - thanks for the catch.

Comment: you made an error, it should be `n - lastPos[A[i]]`, better to use the function `max()`